# Round range to step value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a an array of numbers like this one:

```js
const dataset = [0.5, 2, 1, 93, 67.5, 1, 7, 34];
```

so the min value is 0.5 and the max value is 93. I would like to have the extremis of that dataset rounded to a `step` value.

For example:

- if `step = 5` the result should be `[0, 95]`
- if `step = 10` the result should be `[0, 100]`

the new min value should be always <= the real min value in dataset and the new max value should be always >= the real max value in dataset and they both should be a multiple of `step`.

Note: I should nice if it works also with negative values.

I created the `roundToNearest` function but is not enough to solve my problem:

```js
function computeExtremisRounded(dataset: number[], step: number): [number, number] {
   const [minValue, maxValue] = getMinAndMax(dataset) // suppose it exists
   const roundedMinValue = roundToNearest(minValue, step)
   const roundedMaxValue = roundToNearest(maxValue, step)
   return [roundedMinValue, roundedMaxValue]
}

function roundToNearest(value: number, step: number): number {
  return Math.round(value / step) * step;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must ceil or floor depending on whether you're calculating your max or min:

```
function computeExtremisRounded(dataset: number[], step: number): [number, number] {
   const [minValue, maxValue] = getMinAndMax(dataset) // suppose it exists
   const roundedMinValue = Math.floor(minValue / step) * step
   const roundedMaxValue = Math.ceil(maxValue / step) * step
   return [roundedMinValue, roundedMaxValue]
}
```